# Return mysql query result using Promise

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I'm currently a little confused as to how to properly wait for the promise to finish before returning the result from a query

Here is my current code:

```
const getLeaderboardValues = async () => {
  const SQLConnection = await getSQLConnection();

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    SQLConnection.query(getValuesSQLQuery, (err, result) => {
      if (err) { reject(err) }
      return resolve(result);
    });
    
    SQLConnection.end()
  })
}
const runtime = () => {
  getLeaderboardValues().then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
  })
}
```

The code above does log the correct results while debbugging, i believe this is because i'm giving the code more time to render with the breakpoints, however when running normally i get undefined

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `SQLConnection.end()` line is executing before the query is returned, given it is outside the `query` statement.

The below may solve your issue, however I do not recommend opening a connection and closing it on every request in production systems.

```
const getLeaderboardValues = async () => {
  const SQLConnection = await getSQLConnection();

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    SQLConnection.query(getValuesSQLQuery, (err, result) => {
      if (err) { 
        reject(err) 
        return SQLConnection.end()
      }

      SQLConnection.end()
      return resolve(result);
    });
    
  })
}
const runtime = () => {
  getLeaderboardValues().then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
  })
}
```

Comment: Seems like i have more than one issue, this didn't solve the issue although did point out a future issue, so thanks. The issue I'm facing now is a result of "Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)" while running normally, however when debugging with breakpoints, the result is correct...

Comment: From the error message, it is clearly not because of this part of the code... somehow the database user is not being passed to the connection string when you run "normally", I'd recommend reviewing the piece of code that specifies the user you use to connect to the DB.. if you were using an invalid user XXX, the error message would be "Access denied for user 'XXX'@'localhost'"...